# Linq splitting group if there is missing number

Tags: c#, linq

This one has totally stumped me.

Let's say we have a list of integers

```
var list = new List {
   1,
   2,
   3,
   5,
   6,
   7,
   9,
   10    
};
```

How can I group this where this would be 1-3,5-7,9-10 the group is split where the next integer is missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See if this works.  No for loop, just linq

```
            List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10};
            List<int> splitIndex = list.Skip(1).Select((x,i) => new { x = x, i = i}).Where(x => list[x.i] + 1 != x.x).Select(x => x.i).ToList();
            //add last index
            splitIndex.Add(list.Count - 1);
            var results = splitIndex.Select((x,i) => (i == 0) ? list.Take(x + 1).ToList() : list.Skip(splitIndex[i - 1] + 1).Take(splitIndex[i] - splitIndex[i - 1]).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't achieve it with simple LINQ, but you can write your own extension method that can deal with such grouping.

You have to place it in static class, and call it like normal LINQ.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupSequential (
        this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        var previous = source.First();
        var list = new List<int>() { previous };
        foreach (var item in source.Skip(1))
        {
            if (item - previous != 1)
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<int>();
            }
            list.Add(item);
            previous = item;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

and call it like `list.GroupSequential()`

I think this should work for your needs.

Comment: this actually doesn't work. it separates all of them.

Comment: It may be that you copied a code when I posted it, there was a mistake in condition that I edited out.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Arion that it probably isn't possible with a readable LINQ method chain. @jdweng proved me wrong though :-)

I'd like to offer my alternative solution. It's an extension method, and it utilizes a custom [Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) type.

Range:

```cs
public struct Interval
{
    public Interval(int from, int to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public int From { get; }
    public int To { get; }

    public IEnumerable<int> Members() => Enumerable.Range(From, To - From + 1);
}
```

To get the numbers within the `Range`, you would use Numbers() function. Numbers are lazily generated, thus saving space unless you need them all.

The extension:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Interval> GetIntervals(this IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        var array = numbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        var fromIndex = 0;
        var toIndex = fromIndex;
        for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            var current = array[i];
            if (current == array[toIndex] + 1)
            {
                toIndex++;
            }
            else if (fromIndex != toIndex)
            {
                yield return new Interval(array[fromIndex], array[toIndex]);
                fromIndex = i;
                toIndex = fromIndex;
            }
        }

        if (toIndex != fromIndex)
        {
            yield return new Interval(array[fromIndex], array[toIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

The usage:

```cs
public void Demo()
{
    var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10};

    // 1-3, 5-7, 9-10, lazily generated
    var intervals = list.GetIntervals();
    foreach (var interval in intervals) 
    {
        // [1, 2, 3], then [5, 6, 7], then [9, 10], lazily generated
        var members = interval.Members(); 
        foreach (var numberInRange in members)
        {
            // do something with numberInRange
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be simplified a bit :

```
var list = new List<int> { 1,2,3, 5,6,7, 9,10 };

List<List<int>> result = list.Aggregate(new List<List<int>>(), (L, n) => { 
    if (L.Count < 1 || L.Last().Last() < n - 1) L.Add(new List<int>());
    L.Last().Add(n);
    return L;
});
```

Comment: Good one, single block of code and no supportive variables outside the LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what format you want it back as, but this extension will report the missing numbers in a list and return a list of the missing numbers:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SequenceFindMissings(this IList<int> sequence)
{

    var missing = new List<int>();

    if ((sequence != null) && (sequence.Any()))
    {
        sequence.Aggregate((seed, aggr) =>
                            {
                                var diff = (aggr - seed) - 1;

                                if (diff > 0)
                                    missing.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((aggr - diff), diff));

                                return aggr;
                            });
    }

    return missing;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10};

var missings = list.SequenceFindMissings(); // { 4, 8 }
```

---

Its a topic covered on my blog:

[C# Linq: Find Missing Values in a Sequence of Numbers and Other Sequence Related lists as IEnumerable Extensions](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1032)

Comment: I would like a List<List<int>> back. the lists of int would be the items that are in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this LINQ solution more easy to understand and debug than the accepted one IMHO:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 };

int groupIndex = 0;
int previousNumber = list.First();

var groups = list.Select((n, i) =>
{
  previousNumber = (i == 0) ? list[i] : list[i - 1];
  return new
  {
    Number = n,
    GroupIndex = (i == 0) || (previousNumber + 1 == list[i]) ? groupIndex : ++groupIndex
  };
}).GroupBy(x => x.GroupIndex).Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Number).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to go crazy, you can try the below 1 linq,**

```
    var desiredOutput = string.Join(',', string.Join(',', Enumerable.Range(list.First(), list.Last())).Split(Enumerable.Range(list.First(), list.Last())
            .Except(list).Select(y => y.ToString()).ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(x => string.Concat(x.Trim(',').Split(',').First(), "-", x.Trim(',').Split(',').Last())));
```

---

Or for more clear format, you can try the below

```
        var sequenceOrder = Enumerable.Range(list.First(), list.Last()).ToList();
        var splitters = sequenceOrder.Except(list).Select(y => y.ToString()).ToArray();
        var joinedSequence = string.Join(',', sequenceOrder);
        var result = joinedSequence.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x => string.Concat(x.Trim(',').Split(',').First(), "-", x.Trim(',').Split(',').Last()));
        var desiredOutput = string.Join(',', result);
```